# HTML5 Video autoplay not working

Tags: html, html5-video

I have been looking into how to implement HTML5  videos as a
   background
       video on web and mobile, below is the following code-
       it displays but not autostarts, this is the problem

```
<video width="100%" controls autoplay>
  <source src="video/342125205.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/342125205.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: Show your `video` tag with all attributes you are using.

Comment: Are you testing on desktop or mobile?

Comment: Did you test in wich browser ?

Comment: on desktop i am using chrome browser

Comment: Try muted to see if it is autoplaying like so <video width="100%" controls autoplay muted>

Comment: i am testing here http://www.websiteappo.com/      and this is my video link     http://www.websiteappo.com/img/342125205.mp4

Answer (score 53):

Depending on your Chrome version you might get the new implementation of video autoplay rules:

- Muted autoplay is always allowed.
- Autoplay with sound is allowed if:

  - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
  - On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously play video with sound.
  - On mobile, the user has added the site to his or her home screen.
    Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

Taken from: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

So you can try it muted:

```
<video width="100%" controls autoplay muted>
  <source src="video/342125205.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/342125205.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: <video width="100%" class="landing" controls autoplay loop>
 <source src="img/342125205.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="img/342125205.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 </video>           <script>
$( window ).load(function() {
          $( '.landing' ).get(0).play();
 });
</script>        this code work for me  thank you

Answer (score 16):

I had similar issues with `autoplay` not having any effect regardless of usage of `muted`. Unexpectedly I had success when specifying autoplay as camel case `autoPlay`

Comment: I can't believe it, but this solved the problem for me. Very unexpected and undocumented. I thought HTML was case insensitive!

Comment: Seems it's not working anymore in Chrome 89.

Comment: It happened to me too, I think it's because the video has no audio, and for some reason, the autoplay is playing the audio that the video doesn't have and causes an error.

Answer (score 4):

In React you need to add the attributes of tags in camelCase. So in this case It has to be **autoPlay**.

Answer (score 1):

It's too old thread now. But still I have a suggestion if you want to use.
Instead of the autoplay attribute(because other told it's only work always if it also has muted) you could use one thing:-

```
function playVideo()
{
    document.getElementById("vid").play();
}
```

a very simple function in javascript. Make sure to give your video Id 'vid' or change it here. Video Example

```
<video id="vid" loop controls>
        <source src="Videos/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and in body tag write this:-

```
<body onpageshow="playVideo()">
```

It worked for me. Maybe for you too

Answer (score 1):

Just change `autoplay` as camel case `autoPlay`

```
<video  controls autoPlay loop muted>
    <source  src={myvideo} type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src={myvideo} type="video/ogg"/>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue. The fix is to camelCase `autoPlay`.
So the following should work:

```
<video autoPlay muted>
  <source src="video/342125205.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/342125205.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check browser permissions. If the site is not secure (http), then autoplay on websites will be disabled.
To make changes you can click on the left side of the Address Bar of the browser and click **Allow audio and video**.