# playlist autoplay but has not sound

Tags: javascript

I have a playlist in javascript, when it is muted the video plays automatically, otherwise it doesn't play automatically.

How can I make autoplay and muted false?

My code HTML is:

```html
<video  id="vid" src="main/" style="width:1360px; height:750px; visibility:visibility;"  controls playsinline     >
```

```js
var separador = ";";
var video = document.currentScript.parentElement;
var sec = document.getElementById("valor").textContent;
var playlist = sec.split(separador);
video.volume = 0.1;

var lastSong = null;
var selection = null;
var video = document.getElementById("vid");

video.autoplay = true;
video.muted = true;


video.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom);
//video.muted=false;
function selectRandom() {
  while (selection == lastSong) {

    selection = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);

  }

  lastSong = selection;
  video.src = playlist[selection];

}

selectRandom();
video.play();
```

Comment: You are defining the variable `video` twice - change it to be two separate variables - Also, can you include the HTML into your question?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342545/how-can-i-autoplay-a-video-without-muting) answer your question?

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, it doesn't work changing the variable, it works as long as it is in muted

Comment: Thank you very much, it is indeed the autoplay policy. I can solve it by adding the page as a shortcut on the desktop. The objective is to reproduce the videos on screens in a store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't play a video automatically with sound. There's a thing called "Autoplay Policy", at least for Chrome, but all other browsers are trying to block it.

See more information [here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, it is indeed the autoplay policy. I can solve it by adding the page as a shortcut on the desktop. The objective is to reproduce the videos on screens in a store.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark answers as correct answer after your question, if it's helpful.